# Form não faz validação usando Partial View

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Estou usando `Partial View` para cadastro de `Pessoa`, ou seja, na minha `View` tenho dois `RadioButton`: `Pessoa Fisica` e `Pessoa Juridica`, ao selecionar o `Radio Button` eu faço o seguinte `ajax`:

```
    $(function () {
    $(".radioPessoa").change(function (event) {
        var opcao = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("OpcaoPessoa", "Cadastro")',
            data: { opcao: opcao },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".loadpartial").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Aí, eu tenho esses dois arquivos `.cshtml` que contém os inputs necessários,
Tudo esta funcionando até então, **MAS**, quando eu dou o submit, ele nao valida meus inputs, que coloquei as exigências no meu `Model`

Na minha `View` `Create` eu deixei a classe para receber os `inputs` e o `submit`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="loadpartial">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 semPadding marginCimaBaixo clearfix">
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>

}
```

ai o meu conteúdo dos arquivos `.cshtml` vai carregar na div `, segue meu`Model: `

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo CPF deve ser preenchido")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9.-]{14}", ErrorMessage = "Por favor, preencha o CPF apenas com números.")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }
```

resumindo, ele não valida meus inputs e vai pro `Controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloquei esse código, depois que recebi o `AJAX`

```
 //allow the validation framework to re-prase the DOM
 jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse(); 

 //or to give the parser some context, supply it with a selector
 //jQuery validator will parse all child elements (deep) starting
 //from the selector element supplied
 jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formId");
```